# ASP.NET MVC long waiting times in requests in both development and production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, get

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC and the waiting times for GET requests are quite long both for static and dynamic content.

I am using Windows Azure Shared Websites for production and my localhost for development.

In both of them, nearly all of the GET requests has too long waiting times. For instance, it takes 1 second for waiting and 4 ms for receiving the content. And the job done in server side is nothing fancy, it just returns view with 4 inputs.

As i mention, this problem happens in both my localhost, and Azure. What can be the reason ? or is there a way to learn the actual operation that is causing this wait time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's some server side handler that executes for both static and dynamic content which is taking too long. I would recommending you getting [glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) (`Glimpse.Mvc3` NuGet) which will allow you to see detailed information about the execution that takes place on the server. You will be able to see all methods being executed as well as the time it takes which might help you pinpointing the problem.

As an alternative you could start narrowing down your application by removing functionality until you are able to isolate the problem.

Comment: thanks. I tried it and the problem seems to exist due to ViewResult ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) method of type viewresult. Do you have any idea, why this method execution takes seconds too long while other methods are quite low ?

Comment: You can try some of the optimization tips on this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/08/16/optimizing-mvc-view-lookup-performance.aspx